# I am working on a semantic word search in python using cosine similarity. It is giving me Process finished with exit code 0 without showing an output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, cosine-similarity

using cosine similarity I am trying to find the semantic word comparison. I have posted the code below for reference, in the code, I have added the stopwords, which are the words I don't want to be found during the search. I have opened the text file with which I want the reference words (also given below ) to be compared. I am also adding a limit of 3 words to the search means any word less than three characters is to be considered a stop word. while running the code it is giving me the process finished with exit code 0 and I can't get an output from the code. Would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

```
import math
import re
stopwords = set (["is", "a", "about", "above", "above", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost",
             "alonll", "with", "within", "without", "would", "yet", "you", "your",
             "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "the"])
with open("ref.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


def build_frequency_vector(content: str) -> dict[str, int]:

    vector = {}
    word_seq = re.split("[ ,;.!?]+", content)
    for words in word_seq:
        if words not in stopwords and len(words) >= 3:
            words = words.lower()
            if words in vector:
                vector[words] = vector[words] + 1
            else:
                vector[words] = 1

        return  vector

refWords = ['spain', 'anchovy',
            'france', 'internet', 'china', 'mexico', 'fish', 'industry', 'agriculture', 'fishery', 'tuna', 'transport',
            'italy', 'web', 'communication', 'labour', 'fish', 'cod']

refWordsDict = {}
for refWord in refWords:

    refWordsDict[refWord] = {}
    for line in lines:
        line = line.lower()
        temp = build_frequency_vector(line)
        if refWord not in temp:
            continue

            for word in temp:
                if word not in stopwords and len(word) >= 3 and word != refWord:
                    refWordsDict[refWord][word] = refWordsDict[refWord].get(word, 0) + temp[word]
def product(v1: dict[str, int], v2: dict[str, int]) -> float:
    sp = 0.0
    for word in v1:
        sp += v1[word] * v2.get(word, 0)
    return sp
def cosineSimilarity(s1: str, s2: str) -> float :
    d1 = build_frequency_vector(word1)
    d2 = build_frequency_vector(word2)
    return product(d1, d2) / (math.sqrt(product(d1, d1) * product(d2, d2)))
bests = {}
for word1 in refWords:
    bestSimilarity = 0
    for word2 in refWords:
        if word1 != word2:
            similarity: float = cosineSimilarity(refWordsDict[word1], refWordsDict[word2])
            if similarity > bestSimilarity:
                bestSimilarity = similarity
                bests[word1] = (word2, bestSimilarity)

for item in bests:
    print(item, "->", bests[item])
```

I am very new to python and not able to find a solution.

Comment: The only way this can happen is if `bests` is empty. Try printing `bests` to see what it is. In that case it means your conditionals are never getting executed.